# How to detect concurrency issues in Spring MVC controller?

Tags: multithreading, testing, spring-mvc

In the office we have a controller that will be accessed simultaneously by hundreds of clients on a particularly slow action. There is a risk that our code is not safe for concurrency invocations. How would you create concurrent automated tests to identify potential problems?

Comment: I would carefully analyze the code instead. If you're looking for a tool to execute many conurrent scenarios, then JMeter might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I second the suggestion, you should try and stress test your code as much as possible from jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

Creating automated concurrent testing is problematic. 
 Although there are tools like JMeter that will help to run many concurrent scenarios, 
you may not come up with the desired scenario to detect you synchronization issue. 
What you need to do is invest time in code review + analysis using tools as profiles and/or jvisualvm, and perform a thread dump. On linux you can do this by - 
kill -QUIT process_id where process_id is the PID of your java process. 
 Using this for example you will be able to detect dead-locks. Maybe if you specify what scenarios you see it will be easier to give you more help.